# How to import github maven project as jar file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I want to use the following github project as a compiled one to be referenced by my own eclipse project (java):

`https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils`

**I don't use Maven.** How do I reference this github project so I can use its libraries in my own project? Does it have to be turned into a JAR or is there some other way.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Maybe this link would help: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_Remote_Repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use maven, you may want to download the sources (git checkout), compile them into a jar, and add the jar in your project's build path.
Read: [How to make a jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the project is already on Maven Central or Bintray then you can download the jar from there.

Otherwise you can use [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io) to build the jar for you.